# Slick slider table-cell negative margin

Tags: css, slick.js

This is quite a niche issue, but here goes....

I'm using slick slider and have put together a nested vertical carousel with slider syncing which works great.
I only have 1 CSS issue I just can't resolve.

My vertical slider controls are on the left hand side and the content on the right.
I've used `display:table-cell` on the vertical controls and content so they appear side by side. All working well so far!

I want to add a triangle to the right of the control, which means I need to add a negative left margin to the content area.
This is where I have a problem....it seems `display: table-cell` ignores the left margin.

The image below is what I have - notice the gap between the edge of the control and the border of the content. This is what I'm trying to close up
[image]

The image below is what I'm after - no gap between control and content border
[image]

This is the fiddle I've created https://jsfiddle.net/damiantaylor/njds51yh/220/

Is it possible to fix this issue?

**EDIT** I have tried changing the `display:table-cell` to `display:inline-block` but Slick seems to calculate the width of the content container incorrectly when I do that

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working, but it's a horribly hacky way of piecing the border together.

I'd still love a better answer if there is one!

I've but the border together like this......

```
.vertical-nav-wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 13px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #fe0115;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fe0115;
    border-left: none;
    clear: both;
    border-right: none;
}

.vertical-nav-wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 13px;
    top: 0;
    width: 1;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    clear: both;
    border-right: 1px solid #fe0115;
}
```

the new fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/damiantaylor/njds51yh/263/

**EDIT** if there's another slider/carousel that will handle what I'm trying to achieve better than Slick, I'd accept that as an answer too!